# Convert a string from Java to C++

Tags: java, c++, string, class

I have this string in Java:

```
String op="text1 "+z+" text2"+j+" text3"+i+" "+Arrays.toString(vol);
```

where "z", "j" and "i" are int variables; "toString()" is a function belongs to a class.

```
class Nod
{
    private:
        char *op;
    public:
        char Nod::toString()
        {
        return *op;
        }
}
```

and "vol" is a vector of int variables.

and I want to convert it into C++.

Can you help me please?

**EDIT:**

Sorry because I confuse you, but "toString()" is **not** a function belongs to a class.

"Arrays.toString()" - is a class from Java.

Comment: I'd recommend using an C++ STL <string> and Unicode, not a char * pointer.

Comment: Ok, I will use it; but my question is how to concatenate string with int variables and store the result in a string variable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To append an `int` into string, you can use the [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream oss;

oss << "text1 " << z << " text2" << j << " text3" << i;

std::string str = oss.str();
```

The method [`str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) returns a `string` with a copy of the content of the stream.

**EDIT :**

If you have a `std::vector`, you can do :

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> arr(3);
unsigned int size = arr.size();
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    oss << arr[i];
```

---

Or there is a C++11 way to do all the thing :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> arr(3);

std::string result = "text1 " + std::to_string(z);
result += " text2" + std::to_string(j);
result += " text3" + std::to_string(i) + " ";

for ( auto& el : arr )
    result += std::to_string(el);
```

You can take a look at [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/).

[**Here**](http://ideone.com/RkTX02) is a live example of this code.

*Remember that not all the compilers support C++11 as of right now.*

Comment: Do you know how to translate also "Arrays.toString(vol)"?

Comment: @RemusAvram It depends the container you want to use in C++ ? Did you hear about `std::vector` and `std::array` ?

Comment: vol is a vector of int variables and  "Arrays.toString()" is a java function. What I want is to add the vector of int variables at the end. In java the output it looks like this: "text1 15 text2 10 text3 11 [15, 18, 0]"; where "[15, 18, 0]" is that vector.

Comment: @RemusAvram I edited my post with an example for the vectors and a C++11 sample too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I asked you again because I believed that maybe it is also a function in C++ like in Java, but the only solution is a "for". It is good also a "for", don't understand me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`std::to_string` is another way to do this in C++11 (no need to have an extra `include` for `sstream`):

```
std::string op = "text1 " + std::to_string(num);
```

Comment: Thank you @Oleksiy for your answer! But too bad I can not use a vector of int with this function "to_string()".